# Структура базы данных для мессенджера

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, структуры-данных

пишу приложение - мессенджер, сейчас есть такая структура БД:
[image: Структура бд]

При составлении структуры решил, чат будет отдельной таблицей, т.к. не планирую какого-либо разделения между групповыми чатами и обычными (между 2-мя пользователями).
Сейчас же при разработке сервера, понял, что это не самое удобное решение, т.к. приходится постоянно обращаться в дополнительную ассоциативную таблицу для связи пользователей и чатов (таблица хранит идентификаторы чатов и пользователей).

Решения с добавлением полей (to, from) в таблицу сообщений мне также не нравится, потому что опять же неудобно работать с групповыми чатами.

Вообще, опыта работы с БД почти нет, хотел бы спросить совета здесь, как можно наиболее адекватно организовать структуру БД в данном случае?

P.S. Проект ASP.NET Core + PostgreSQL (работаю через EF Core)

Comment: Схема выглядит нормально.  Что значит «обращаться в […] таблицу»?  Это же обычный `JOIN`.

Comment: Пришлось создать таблицу для организации связи "многие ко многим" между пользователями и чатами. Приходится, допустим, при обновлении информации о чате или удалении пользователя, также редактировать эту таблицу. Мне это очень не нравится, может, возможно без "многие ко многим" как-то спроектировать?..

Comment: Непонятно.  В вашей промежуточной таблице же только айдишники.  Что там обновлять?  А для удаления есть триггеры или каскад.

Comment: Про каскад я что-то и не подумал, спасибо. Уберу лишнюю логику удаления с сервера. Наверное, я и правда что-то придумываю не то, просто всегда старался избегать "многие ко многим". Оставлю как есть

Comment: А зачем удалять пользователей ? Вот был диалог в чате, два пользователя переписывались. А потом удалился и все сообщения вместе с ним ... и история чата получается какой то рваной, только от того кто остался сообщения есть, а между ними ничего нет. По моему удалять вообще не надо пользователей, только помечать как каких нибудь скрытых и возможно обезличенных

Comment: Тоже верно, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

Связь многие-ко-многим тблиц User <-> Chat будет через таблицу Message, никакой дополнительной таблицы для нее создавать не обязательно, но может понадобится для повышения производительности, надо смотреть с конкретной СУБД.

В таблице Message надо добавить дату/время публикации. В остальном структура таблиц выглядит хорошо.