# Как реализоватт хранение списка лиалогов в БД для мессенджера?

Tags: база-данных, список

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне реализовать хранение списка диалога (список всех Личный Сообщений с каждым из пользователей с кем он общался)

То есть, имеется страница со списком диалогов, но как мне этот список для каждого из пользователей сохранять?

Была мысль сделать так:

Если Алиса напишет Бобу, то создастся таблица в БД с именем 1_2 , где 1 - это ид Алисы, а 2 это ид Боба, ещё пример: Вера (id 152) и Гоша (id 281) -> создаются таблица с именем 152_281, а в внутри этой таблицы будут уже сообщения

А вывод списка будет осуществляться по поиску всех таблиц где есть ID пользователя который ищет. К примеру: Боб (id 2) -> скрипт ищет все названия БД где есть 2_* или *_2, пример вывода списка: 1_2 2_283 2_395 2_928

Но мне кажется что это не правильно было бы так делать, если не правильно, то подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Например, две таблицы: Users (id, name), Messages (id, send_by, send_to, text, date)

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, извините, я наверное не совсем точно описал что хотел. Мне нужно вывести список всех диалогов пользователя

Comment: Правильно составленный SQL-запрос вернёт вам список диалогов. Если у вас не планируются групповые чаты, вполне подойдет такая структура (из двух таблиц).
В ином случае, можете рассмотреть [такую структуру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158882/443096), но запросы проще не будут.